# AngularJS - split controller functions in multiple files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new in AngularJS and I'm doing a refactor of an AngularJS application and I noticed that there is a single controller file with a lot of functions that manipulate and set scope variables.

Following an example:

```
test.controller('testCtrl', function testCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.init_filters = function() {
        $scope.filter_1 = [];
        $scope.filter_2 = [];
        $scope.filter_3 = [];
        $scope.filter_4 = [];
        $scope.filter_5 = [];
    };

    $scope.showChanges = function() {
        if ($scope.item_list.length > 0) {
            $scope.messages = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.item_list.length; i++) {
                $scope.messages.push($scope.item_list[i].message);
            }
            $scope.another_function();
        }else{
            // other stuff
        }  
    };

    //other functions like these

}
```

So, I would like to split these functions in multiple JS files. I searched about this problem and I found that in a lot of case is used a service. But I think that this is not my case, because I need to working on directly on the controller's scope. 
I mean, I don't want a separated function that get as parameters some scope variables and return the variable.

So, what is the best practices for doing something like this? is it possible?

Comment: if you want to follow a modular approach. Coffee-script with grunt allows to do it. Please have a look at this package `https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use multiple files then split the definition to multiple files by passing the scope to another method and then define the rest of methods there.

**File1**

```
app.controller('CtrlOne', function($scope){
app.expandControllerCtrlOne($scope);

});
```

**File2**

```
app.expandControllerCtrlOne = function($scope)
{

}
```

Check this [`video`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg)

Answer (score 2):

As you said the code you found for controller is large one so there are multiple ways in angular js that you can implemented the separation of code.

I will suggest you to go with following approach:

1. Use **service** to add those code in it which you need in other places as well and you know that this code does not require scope object..
2. Use **factory** to add some Utility kind of functions. The collection of logic which does not require scope object again...
3. As controller code is too large, I think **View/UI** of same also being as per wrote...
   So for this you can go with **creating directives for section in view**..
   Where-ever you think this peace of view section can be separate and standalone logical functionality that you can move into directive.
   There are three ways to create directive with scopes:

> A. Shared Scope B. Isolated Scope C: shared and Isolated scope

In this ways may you can at-least make your controller code readable and looks modular.

Let say::

```
module.controller('longRunController', function() {


    @TYPE 1 code
    // some code which fetch dat from API
    // some code which save variable and objects which can used in another controller or directives
    // some code which need to passed to other controller even after route changes


    @TYPE 2
    // some code which is only related this controller but has some bussiness logic
    // some code which is a kind of utility functino

    @TYPE 3
    // all $scope related variable $watch, $scope and related variables
    // some code of perticular section of which VIEW which handle by this controller

});
```

Consider in above patter your controller code has:

1. So type 1 code can be moved to Service
2. type 2 code can be moved to factory
3. type 3 code can be move to directives

Comment: Thanks for the answer! can you provide me an example for the point 3?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `$scope` as a parameter to the external function.
And because you just use the objectreference, all changes you made in your external functions are made on the `$scope` object from your controller.

```
test.controller('testCtrl', function testCtrl($scope) 
{
   showChanges($scope);
});


...

function showChanges(scope)
{
    scope.param1 = "Hello World";
}
```